# Wrong datetime in sqlite expert personal

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to write to my sqlite db from visual studio in c#. When using datetime. Now in visual studio it shows me the correct date and time but when writing to the db it shows something like `1899/30/12`. Why is that? Here is my code:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO tblLicenseInfo (ID, UserID, MachineID, ExpirationDate, DateOfChange, LicenseKey)
                                       VALUES(1, 1, 1, @test, @test, 'sdfsafge45345345');", SqLite);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@test", DateTime.Now);
SqLite.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqLite.Close();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the type of your `ExpirationDate` and `DateOfChange` columns?

Comment: so theres something wrong with the cmd.Parameters.Add line, right?

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now is in the incorrect format, so you have 2 options:

- Use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as value. This is a SQLite keyword.

Or

- Format Datetime: `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why [`SQLiteParameterCollection.Add(String,Object)` method](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameterCollection~Add%28String,Object%29.html) overload doesn't work because it says:

> Adds a SQLiteParameter to the SQLiteParameterCollection given the
>   parameter name and value.

As an alternative, you can use other overloads or [`AddWithValue`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameterCollection~AddWithValue.html) as well like;

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@test", SQLiteType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", DateTime.Now);
```

More informations;

- [Using Parameters](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Parameters.html)

But wait a second.. You said your column type is `DATETIME` but there is no data type like that in  `SQLite`.

From [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic
>     Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Please tell the real type of your columns. I assume `DateTime.Now` doesn't fit these 3 type formats (or values) and that's why you get `1899/30/12` used as a "default" date in SQLite.

From [Date And Time Functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

> The date and time functions use a subset of IS0-8601 date and time
>   formats. The date() function returns the date in this format:
>   YYYY-MM-DD.

I feel like if you make your column type as `TEXT` and if you send your `DateTime.Now` with `YYYY-MM-dd` format, your code should work;

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@test", SQLiteType.TEXT).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("YYYY-MM-dd");
```